# Get Event dates from my Google+ Page

Tags: json, api, events, google-plus

**Hi everyone**

I have a Google+ page, and i would like to display all events created by this page on my website, but for for some reason i cannot find the date, time or place of this anywhere in the json output i get from the Google+ API.

The json output below display all the activity on my page (not much) and in there i have two event, but i cannot see the information needed anywhere.

> https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/103518584309304034966/activities/public?maxResults=20&pageToken=Next&fields=items&key={Removed my API Key}

I generated the json output on this page, by filling out the form below with: 103518584309304034966, public, 20 next, blank:

> https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list

I hope someone know where i can get the date, time and place on a Google+ event, keep in mind that this is not a real user so i don't have a Google Calandar

Answer (score 3):

The closest you would get would be to [list activities](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=103518584309304034966&collection=public&_h=1&) as you suggested and then search within the results list for event activities.

As you mentioned, event activities do not include the event time, location, and date. However, you could, however put something into the description indicating the date/time and could start from there for programmatically pulling the dates.

This information could be made available in the future, so please [join the Google+ community for Google+ developers](https://plus.google.com/communities/113527920160449995981) to stay aware of any updates.